# Proper way for debug symbols in javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

When i write javascript code , i usually insert a debug symbols to help me out .

Let me illustrate what i mean by example :

```
var debug = true;

/* Some event handler */
onValueChange = function(e, ui){
    var new_value = dom.volume.slider("value");
    conf.value = new_value;

    if (debug) {
        console.log("Value changed to : " + new_value);
    }
}
```

when i finish, i don't want all this debug related code to be part of my release/minified codebase .
what is the convention for this sort of thing ? are there any (non IDE based) tools available ?
I am looking for solutions working with exiting codebase and for starting a new project in the future .

Or what other debugging strategies exist in javascript world ?

Comment: UglifyJS does: http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - thanks thats very helpful but what if i already have a system in place. How do I remove the existing code?

Comment: @bhb: ... for example, no automated system, Closure, etc.?

Comment: No error in code, please check other errors in console

Comment: @AmitAgrawal: This isn't about errors in the code given, that's just an example.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy can we use regex in UglifyJS to remove the unwanted code

Comment: @bhb: the nature of how such a program would work would preclude using a regular expression for this sort of thing.

Comment: Closure compiler does remove dead code as well. When you declare `debug=false` as a constant, it will remove all those if-statements.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this logging code you will need to write a parser! I suggest that you go with a different debugging strategy. `console.log` is no doubt useful but a full fledged debugger like: the one provided by Chrome DevTools, is strongly advised.
You can inject break points at any position in your code with `debugger;`. Going with a real debugger will make your life as a developer much more easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use FireBug in Fire Fox .  it will help you a lot to debug java script code.

Comment: Yes. However the OP did ask for a tool to remove debugging code in production, not for a debugger. Anyway: Welcome to StackOverflow!